# YouTube Java Client API: Why is the Video.getSnippet() method returning null?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

I recently managed to successfully call the YouTube API to retrieve the view count of a video so I decided to try to fetch the title as well but I don't understand what's going wrong.
This code

```
YouTube.Videos.List list = youtube.videos().list(Arrays.asList("statistics"));
list.setId(Arrays.asList("video id here"));
String apiKey = "[redacted]";
list.setKey(apiKey);  
Video v = list.execute().getItems().get(0);
v.getStatistics().getViewCount()
```

returns the view count just fine but then I tried this code:

```
    String title = "";
    title = v.getSnippet().getTitle();
```

and I got a `NullPointerException` because `v.getSnippet()` is returning `null`...do I need to assign some kind of value somewhere for something before calling the API in order for it to actually fetch the data that's supposed to be in the `VideoSnippet` object?

For convenience, here is the API docs: https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-youtube/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official docs of the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint, to retrieve the [`snippet`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet) object associated to the video of which ID you're passing on to the endpoint, you have to include `snippet` within the names you pass on to the [`part`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part) request parameter.

When using the generated Java libraries [Google Java API Client Services](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services) -- specifically [that corresponding to YouTube Data API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-youtube/v3) --, that boils down to having your `Arrays.asList("statistics")` replaced with `Arrays.asList("snippet", "statistics")`.